# How can the bytes in libc::sockaddr.sa_data be interpreted as an IP address?

Tags: linux, rust, libc

How can I interpret the bytes in the `sa_data: [c_char; 14]` field of `libc::sockaddr`?

I would like to interpret the `sockaddr` as a `std::net::IpAddr` but I can't find documentation about which of those bytes mean what.

Comment: Refer here : http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

For those, what order are the bytes in? E.g. in sockaddr_in there's a u32 address field; is that platform order or network order?